How do I do Texturing and Shading with this Spider-Man PS4 Model?
Hello all I have been getting back into Blender after a few years, and I've been trying to texture and shade this Spider-Man model I found online.

While I think I am getting it down I have a few questions on how to properly shade it using the textures/images provided to me.
'
If anyone can help, I don't know what to do with some of the textures and materials, I know what to do with the normal maps (labeled _n) and the gloss maps. (labeled _g)
But I don't know what to do with the rest of the files and I would like to learn. Any help would be appreciated thank you!

This is my current node setup with the images/textures/maps I have applied so far.
https://sketchfab.com/3d-models/peter-parker-spider-man-into-the-spider-verse-2ee34540c9f149ed9d09e3bd96b703e3
This is the link to download I want to get all the textures and maps applied in the proper locations to match as close as possible to the movie and game.
Here are some examples:


And for reference here is what I have so far:
cycles:

Eevee:


don't forget to switch the normal map image texture node from Color Space > sRGB to Non-Color
